# add attributes on individual grouped products - woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to know if I can add attributes on individual grouped products.. For example, I have set up my main Group Product - Fishing Shirt. 
Under this Group Product I have set up 3 simple products or "child products" which are mens, womens, kids - these simple products are "hidden" and linked to my main Group Product which is the fishing shirt.

Now what I want to do is set the following sizes to my simple products so customers can choose different sizes.
Mens: XS, S, M, L, XL
Womens: 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
Kids: 4y, 6y, 8y, 10y, 12y, 14y

I have added attributes to each simple product but these do not show on the website screen. Is there a way to do this?
If not, what would be the best way to set this out on my website?

I have a main Fishing Shirt which is available for Mens, Womens and Kids fitted sizes. I would like customers to be able to select any size and QTY under each gender.

Hopefully someone can help me, Ive been looking for hours on the net for an answer!
Thanks :)

Comment: This is not possible under grouped products as each linked product should need to be a variable product and so it will not work...

Comment: Thanks! does this mean the best way for me to set this out would be to have Mens, Womens and kids shirt all individual products? Even though they are the same shirt? It's seems as though I cannot have them all under the same product with their different sizes allocated to specific gender